# Changing directory with same database works for SuiteCRM?

Tags: git, crm, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am planning to replace my old code VCS repository with new  VCS repository. I have following directory structure for crm in my project directory :

```
/htdocs/my_repo/my_app/crm
```

Above crm is configured to point `my_db`, Now the older repository is going to be replaced with new repository, directory structure will become as follows :

```
/htdocs/new_repo/my_app/crm
```

I am going to keep database contents intact, will copy crm directory from old repo to new repo. If required I will change the document root to new crm setup folder. Will this approach work ? Or Do I need reinstall suite crm ?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the directory path will not effect your data. However you will probably need to run a repair and rebuild a few times.